# Nav bar in Bootstrap

Tags: menu, nav

In bootstrap my menu will not work in google chrome, it works in all the other browsers.

Strange thing is I have one drop down and the those links work, but no the main items on the menu bar.

http://shilohplainfield.org

Comment: I believe I answered your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could post a screenshot? I see no issues.

I suggest that you clear your browser cache in your Chrome browser because I see *no* differences between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on my Macbook Pro.

The operation I observed on all browsers were identical:

```
1) hovering the mouse curser highlights the menu items.
2) you have to click to get the pulldown menu (which I personally don't love)
3) only the about has a pull down .
4) when you navigate to other pages the "about" and such may or may not be there (don't recommend)
```

Good luck!